# while loop for option tag in a drop down box in php not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to allocate options in drop down box using while loop.
The options appear blank on the page.
No errors shown.

```
<?php 
$dbstate = new DB();
if (!$dbstate->open()) {
die ($dbstate->error());
    }
if (!$dbstate->query("SELECT * FROM external_details order by external_id")) {
      die ($dbstate->error());
    }
?>
<select name="selstate" >
<option value="0">Subject</option>
<?php   while ($row = $dbstate->fetchAssoc()) {?>           
    <option value="<?= $row['external_id']?>">
    <?= $row['name']?>
        </option>
<?php
     }
$dbstate->freeResult();
$dbstate->close();
?>
```

Comment: that should probably be `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and not `fetchAssoc`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why? It looks like he's using a different API (maybe PEAR?).

Comment: i have a function name _fetchAssoc_ that calls `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: @Barmar I didn't know that was or could be PEAR. I don't know all APIs. Seems like OP has a function calling `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: If this is all of your code you also appear not to be closing that `<select>` tag.

Comment: It looks like it should work. Do you have `short_open_tags` enabled?

Comment: @cry0_89 You probably need to echo `$row`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats what the `<?=` is supposed to do ;-)

Comment: @Potherca Oh... I didn't know that *till now*, thanks (noted)

Comment: @Fred-ii- No problem. PHP can be a sneaky little language at times :-D

Comment: @cry0_89 Can you tell us what the exact HTML is that is output? 
"The options appear blank on the page" 
is a bit vague.

Comment: I'm suspecting `<option value="0">`

Comment: @Potherca I have 5 entries in the database and it shows 5 empty options in the drop down.
`selstate=0&selstate=<%3F%3D+%24row%5B%27external_id%27%5D%3F>`
This is what is shown in the title bar when i change the form method to get.

Comment: @Barmar It worked when i changed `<?=` to `<?php echo`.
I guess the `short_open_tags` was disabled.
Thank you

Comment: At this point I would be *really* interested to see what happens when your run `<?php var_dump(ini_get('short_open_tag')); ?>` as it looks as if your short tags are not enabled. You should be getting `<option value=""></option>` in your HTML, in which case `selstate` should just be an empty string.

Comment: @Potherca Yes it was a problem with the `short_open_tag`

Comment: Nevermind, you already got it ;-)

Comment: @Barmar Seems like I was "partially" right about the echo. *"On the right track."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either enable the `short_open_tags` option in your `php.ini`, or change `<?=` to `<?php echo`